# Really Weird Result On BatchNorm On tensorflow 2.1

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, transfer-learning, batch-normalization

I got a very weird result on a Model. Well, I train it, and it got a result of roughly 99.5% accuracy on training, but like you see in the image below the validiation result is so weird.

[Training log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkTEi.png)

So after training, I test my model (on both training, validiation and test data) and I got a very very weird result. When I call the model without training=True, the result is almost 1 every where (my model is binary classifier, so the last model is dense(1) with sigmoid activation). The actually weird is when I test with: model(test_tensor,training=True), I got a reasonable result, when I can reproduce the result of 99.5 % on train set and surprising,98.5% on test set. I doubt it due to the BatchNorm layer,since it is a only layer in my model act different in training and testing phase. So I test the result to see if the moving_mean and moving_variance is learn during training, and yes, it acctualy learn (since it not zero and one, the default value ) and actually it is used in testing time( I test using the moving_mean and variance of the batchnorm and apply it to the output of the previous layer . I'm so tired to figure our what really happening. So anybody have an idea what really going on ?

My model is here :

```
import tensorflow as tf
input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(224,224,3), name='input')
pretrained_model = tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.MobileNetV2(include_top=False, 
weights='imagenet')
pretrained_model_output = pretrained_model(input_layer)
global_avg = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(pretrained_model_output)
dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=512)(global_avg)
dense = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(dense)
dense = tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(dense)
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1,activation='sigmoid')(dense)
model = tf.keras.Model(input_layer, output)
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e- 
3),loss=tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy,metrics=['accuracy'])
```

My test on test data that show the weird result :
    [weird result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Niod.png)

My entire code can be found here
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1jImiW0Sn3HOGgo-pUb-5TWVcwIRX-HSF

Answer (score 0):

Well, I find the answer for this question. It due to the momentum of batchnorm, since you fine-tune the model on pretty small dataset, you should set the momentum low (so that it can up date moving mean and moving variance fast). The momentum default on tensorflow is 0.99, set it to 0.9 and it would fine.